# How can we update and recall div(id="someid",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup')?

Tags: html, r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

If you run the below app in your directory, click save and relaunch the app you would notice that all the inputs in sidepanel are getting saved in sample.RData. The saved values are also getting recalled which we need for the user. If you load sample.RData in your Rstudio you would find the values for input$CategoryA, input$CategoryB and so on also get saved but not getting recalled. I am not sure if there is any easier way of achieving this. If yes I am fine to do it. Questions:-

1. How can I recall the checkboxgroup input id(s) created in div(id=)
   statements?
2. Is it the right way of doing it or am I making it too
   complex for the objective?
3. I am not saving them properly I guess. How do I save them like other inputs?
4. How shall I recall them from the sample.RData file like other inputs?
   My objective is to give users a dynamic interface where they can categorise variable names dynamically from category A to J (10 in numbers) Each variable name (column name) can fall in multiple categories, hence the option of checkbox. Once user has selected them someone can close the app and come back later (desktop version). When they relaunch it all other input selections should be in place like last time. With the help of this portal I am able to save the inputs in sidebarpanel, but the mainpanel ones are not getting recalled. I am giving the code below. However the actual app has lot more variables on side bar panel and mainpanel. I am seeking desperate help to save these input id(s) from div html.
   The moment I un-comment # updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "CategoryA", choices = CategoryA, selected = CategoryA) it says object CategoryA not found. I am trying to update the checkbox input (line commented above) but to no avail. If I can recall for one input I can try the same for Category B to J.

Code for the app below:-

```
library(shiny)
library(pryr)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyFiles)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

if(!file.exists("mydata.csv")){
  x = data.frame(Column1=seq(as.Date('2018/11/01'), as.Date('2018/11/20'), by="day"),
                 Column2=rep(c("TypeA", "TypeB"), each=10),
                 Column3= rep(c(14, 11.5, 12, 11, 13.5, 11, 12.5, 12, 11.5, 6.5), each=2), 
                 Column4 = rep(c(30.99, 32.99, 29.99, 33.99, 36.99, 34.99, 11.99, 32.99, 13.99, 16.99), each=2),
                 Column5 = rep(c(10.99, 12.99, 19.99, 13.99, 16.99, 14.99, 14.99, 12.94, 13.90, 16.80), each=2),
                 Column6 = rep(c(20.99, 22.99, 29.99, 23.99, 26.99, 24.99, 24.99, 22.94, 23.90, 26.80), each=2),
                 Column7 = rep(c(50.99, 52.99, 59.99, 53.99, 56.99, 54.99, 54.99, 52.94, 53.90, 56.80), each=2),
                 Column8 = rep(c(60.99, 62.99, 69.99, 63.99, 66.99, 64.99, 64.99, 62.94, 63.90, 66.80), each=2))
  write.csv(x, "mydata.csv")
}

settings_path <- getwd()

ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("save_file", "Save to file:", value="sample.RData"),
        actionButton("save", "Save input value to file"),
        p(),
        p(),
        uiOutput("load"),
        uiOutput("file"),
        p(),
        selectInput("Browse", label = "Time-Period", choices = c("","Weekly", "Monthly", "Quartely" , "Yearly"), selected = NULL),
        uiOutput('select1'),
        textInput("text1", label = "Type your selection",value = ""),
        p(),
        uiOutput('select2'),
        textInput("text2", label = "Type your selection",value = ""),
        p(),
        uiOutput('select3'),
        textInput("text3", label = "Type your selection",value = ""),
        p(),
        uiOutput('select4'),
        textInput("text4", label = "Type your selection",value = ""),
        p(),
        uiOutput('select5'),
        textInput("text5", label = "Type your selection",value = ""),
        p()

      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Category Selection",
                   fluidPage(
                     fluidRow(
                       column(12,
                              wellPanel(
                                div(id="CategoryA",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                    div(id="CategoryB",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                        div(id="CategoryC",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                            div(id="CategoryD",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                                div(id="CategoryE",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                                    div(id="CategoryF",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                                        div(id="CategoryG",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                                            div(id="CategoryH",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                                                div(id="CategoryI",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                                                    div(id="CategoryJ",class='shiny-input-checkboxgroup',
                                                                        DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "mytable"),
                                    style = "font-size : 80%"))))))))))
                              )))),
                   verbatimTextOutput('sel')
          )

        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  # render a selectInput with all RData files in the specified folder
  last_save_path <- file.path(settings_path, "last_input.backup")
  if(file.exists(last_save_path)){
    load(last_save_path)
    if(!exists("last_save_file")){
      last_save_file <- NULL
    }
  } else {
    last_save_file <- NULL
  }

  if(!is.null(last_save_file)){
    updateTextInput(session, "save_file", "Save to file:", value=last_save_file)
  }

  output$load <- renderUI({
    choices <- list.files(settings_path, pattern="*.RData")
    selectInput("input_file", "Select input file", choices, selected = last_save_file)
  })

  # render a selectInput with all csv files in the specified folder so that user can choose the version
  output$file <- renderUI({
    choices.1 <- list.files(settings_path, pattern="*.csv")
    selectInput("input_csv", "Select csv file", choices.1)
  })

  # Load a csv file and update input
  data = eventReactive(input$input_csv, {
    req(input$input_csv)
    read.csv(file.path(settings_path,input$input_csv),
             header = TRUE,
             sep = ",")
  })

  variables <- reactive(colnames(data()[-1]))
  toolkit <- reactiveValues()
  #Display Names of the selected dataset - First Set
  output$select1 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    req(variables())
    selectInput(inputId = "my_btn1", label = "Variable:",choices = c("", variables()),multiple =F)
  })

  #Display Text of the selected variable - First Set
  observeEvent(input$my_btn1, {
    req(data())
    req(input$my_btn1)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text1", label = "Type your selection", value = isolate(input$text1))
  })

  #Display Time Dimension Variable
  observeEvent(input$my_btn1, {
    req(data())
    req(input$my_btn1)
    req(input$text1)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "Browse", label = "Time-Period", choices = c("","Weekly", "Monthly", "Quartely" , "Yearly"), selected  = isolate(input$Browse))
  })


  #Display Names of the selected dataset - Second Set
  output$select2 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    req(variables())
    selectInput(inputId = "my_btn2", label = "Variable:",choices = c("", variables()),multiple =F)
  })

  #Display Text of the selected variable - Second Set
  observeEvent(input$my_btn2, {
    req(data())
    req(input$my_btn2)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text2", label = "Type your selection", value = isolate(input$text2))
  })

  #Display Names of the selected dataset - Third Set
  output$select3 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    req(variables())
    selectInput(inputId = "my_btn3", label = "Variable:",choices = c("", variables()),multiple =F)
  })


  #Display Text of the selected variable - Third Set
  observeEvent(input$my_btn3, {
    req(data())
    req(input$my_btn3)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text3", label = "Type your selection", value = isolate(input$text3))
  })

  #Display Names of the selected dataset - Fourth Set
  output$select4 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    req(variables())
    selectInput(inputId = "my_btn4", label = "Variable:",choices = c("", variables()),multiple =F)
  })

  #Display Text of the selected variable - Fourth Set
  observeEvent(input$my_btn4, {
    req(data())
    req(input$my_btn4)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text4", label = "Type your selection", value = isolate(input$text4))
  })

  #Display Names of the selected dataset - Fifth Set
  output$select5 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    req(variables())
    selectInput(inputId = "my_btn5", label = "Variable:",choices = c("", variables()),multiple =F)
  })

  #Display Text of the selected variable - Fifth Set
  observeEvent(input$my_btn5, {
    req(data())
    req(input$my_btn5)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text5", label = "Type your selection", value = isolate(input$text5))
  })

  observeEvent({
    input$my_btn1
    input$my_btn2
    input$my_btn3
    input$my_btn4
    input$my_btn5},{
      row_names <- variables()[!(variables() %in% c(input$my_btn1,input$my_btn2,input$my_btn3,input$my_btn4,input$my_btn5))]
      mymatrix <- matrix((1:10), nrow = length(row_names), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE,dimnames = list(row_names, c("CategoryA",
                                                                                                                "CategoryB", "CategoryC", "CategoryD", "CategoryE", "CategoryF","CategoryG",
                                                                                                                "CategoryH","CategoryI", "CategoryJ")))
      ##Put the for loop here
      for (i in seq_len(nrow(mymatrix))) {
        mymatrix[i, 1] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryA", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 2] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryB", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 3] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryC", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 4] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryD", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 5] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryE", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 6] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryF", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 7] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryG", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 8] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryH", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 9] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryI", row_names[i]
        )
        mymatrix[i, 10] = sprintf(
          ifelse(i == 1,
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>',
                 '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>'),
          "CategoryJ", row_names[i]
        )
      }
      toolkit$mymatrix <- mymatrix

      # updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "CategoryA", choices = isolate(input$CategoryA), selected = isolate(input$CategoryA))
    })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(toolkit$mymatrix,
                                       escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, class = 'cell-border stripe',
                                       options = list( initComplete = JS(
                                         "function(settings, json) {",
                                         "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#0B3861', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                         "}"),ordering = FALSE, scroller = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
                                         autoWidth = TRUE, scrollY = "525px", bPaginate = FALSE,
                                         searching = FALSE, columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"))),
                                       callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                                                var $this = $(this.node());
                                                $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                                                $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');});
                                                Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                                                Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());
                                                $(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});")
  )

  output$sel <- renderPrint({
    str(input$CategoryA)
    str(input$CategoryB)
    str(input$CategoryC)
    str(input$CategoryD)
    str(input$CategoryE)
    str(input$CategoryF)
    str(input$CategoryG)
    str(input$CategoryH)
    str(input$CategoryI)
    str(input$CategoryJ)
  }
    )




  # Save input when click the button
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    validate(
      need(input$save_file != "", message="Please enter a valid filename")
    )

    #This should recall the second dependent list
    last_save_file <- input$save_file
    save(last_save_file,  file=last_save_path)

    my_btn1 = input$my_btn1
    text1 = input$text1
    Browse = input$Browse
    my_btn2 = input$my_btn2
    text2 = input$text2
    my_btn3 = input$my_btn3
    text3 = input$text3
    my_btn4 = input$my_btn4
    text4 = input$text4
    my_btn5 = input$my_btn5
    text5 = input$text5
    CategoryA = input$CategoryA

    save(my_btn1, text1, Browse, my_btn2, text2, my_btn3, text3, my_btn4, text4, my_btn5, text5,
         CategoryA,
         file=file.path(settings_path, input$save_file))
  })

  # Load an RData file and update input
  observeEvent(input$input_file, {
    req(input$input_file)
    load(file.path(settings_path, input$input_file))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "my_btn1", label = "Variable:", choices = c("", variables()), selected = my_btn1)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text1", label = "Type your selection", value  = text1)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "Browse", label = "Time-Period", choices = Browse, selected  = Browse)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "my_btn2", label = "Variable:", choices = c("", variables()), selected = my_btn2)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text2", label = "Type your selection", value  = text2)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "my_btn3", label = "Variable:", choices = c("", variables()), selected = my_btn3)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text3", label = "Type your selection", value  = text3)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "my_btn4", label = "Variable:", choices = c("", variables()), selected = my_btn4)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text4", label = "Type your selection", value  = text4)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "my_btn5", label = "Variable:", choices = c("", variables()), selected = my_btn5)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text5", label = "Type your selection", value  = text5)
    # updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "CategoryA", choices = CategoryA, selected = CategoryA)


  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I dont have any stack bounty to offer. However any help would be much appreciated and I can vote.

Comment: You should really have a look at [bookmarks](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033261/save-and-load-user-selections-based-on-file-selection-rshiny/53046820#53046820)

Comment: @ismirsehregal - I know but somehow the recipients dont want bookmarks. I was desperately waiting for your solution on this. What shall I do finally as per your suggestion. Do you think your earlier approach of saving things can be replicated for div(id=) type of inputs or shall I start implementing bookmarks? Many Many thanks for responding.